# angularjs ng-click not working

Tags: javascript

JavaScript define controller and then call function by `$hhtp` and in `$scope` define model and function that I want to call:

```js
myApp.controller('ProfileTweets', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$http({
        url: '../ProfilesName/',
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function (itemdata) {
        $scope.ProfilesName = itemdata.data;
    });
 $scope.loaddata = function () {
        alert('hiii');
    }
}]);
```

And in html I'm calling function `loaddata()` as show in code below

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" dir="rtl" style="width:100%;" ng-model="ProfilesName" ng-options="Profiles.profile_name for Profiles in ProfilesName" ng-change="loaddata()"> </select>
 </div>
```

`ng-change` not working, nothing happen. How to fix it?

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: so bad question and code format, how we will help?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had forgot to place the ng-controller directive, it wont work without it

```js
myApp.controller('ProfileTweets', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$http({
    url: '../ProfilesName/',
    method: 'GET'
}).then(function (itemdata) {
    $scope.ProfilesName = itemdata.data;
});
 $scope.loaddata = function () {
    alert('hiii');
}
}]);
```

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="ProfileTweets">
                  <select class="form-control" 
                        dir="rtl" style="width:100%;" 
                        ng-model="ProfilesName" 
                        ng-options="Profiles.profile_name for Profiles in                                                       ProfilesName" 
                        ng-change="loaddata()"> 
                  </select>
 </div>
```